# Attempted import error: 'FaPencil' is not exported from 'react-icons/fa'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new to ReactJS, now i want to include ( React-icons ) in my project but it give me error. could you please help me .

> **Error :**  Attempted import error: 'FaPencil' is not exported from
>   'react-icons/fa'

Code is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FaPencil } from "react-icons/fa";
import { FaTrash } from "react-icons/lib/fa/trash";

export default class Note extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="note">
        <p>Learn React</p>
        <span>
          <button onClick={this.edit} id="edit">
            <FaPencil />
          </button>
          <button onClick={this.remove} id="remove">
            <FaTrash />
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did the answer below help?  If so, please mark as correct. Thank you

Comment: react has changed its library's. Are you still stuck with this? The following link is the place to look..... https://react-icons.netlify.com/#/icons/fa

Answer (score 2):

```
import FaPencil from 'react-icons/lib/fa/pencil'
```

You don't need to destructure since you're pointing directly to the file. Using `react-icons` it's helpful to go to the `node_modules` folder to see where icons live.

Comment: or `import { FaPencil } from 'react-icons/fa`